# Assert in Kaldi when used with GStreamer

Tags: gstreamer, kaldi

Using GStreamer plugin from [Alumae](https://github.com/alumae/gst-kaldi-nnet2-online) and the following pipeline :

`appsrc source='appsrc' ! wavparse ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! queue !  kaldinnet2onlinedecoder <parameters snipped> ! filesink location=/tmp/test`

I always get the following assert that I don't understand
`KALDI_ASSERT(current_log_post_.NumRows() == info_.frames_per_chunk /
               info_.opts.frame_subsampling_factor &&
current_log_post_.NumCols() == info_.output_dim);`

What is this assert error about ? How to fix it ?

FYI, the data pushed into the pipeline come from a streamed wav file and replacing *kaldinnetonlinedecoder* with *wavenc* correctly generate a Wav file instead of a text file at the end.

**EDIT**
Here are the parameters used:

```
use-threaded-decoder=0   
model=/opt/en/final.mdl   
word-syms=<word-file>  
fst=<fst_file>
mfcc-config=<mfcc-file>  
ivector-extraction-config=/opt/en/ivector-extraction/ivector_extractor.conf  
max-active=10000  
beam=10.0  
lattice-beam=6.0  
do-endpointing=1  
endpoint-silence-phones=\"1:2:3:4:5:6:7:8:9:10\"  
traceback-period-in-secs=0.25  
num-nbest=10
```

For your information, using the pipeline textual representation in python works but coding it (i.e using Gst.Element_Factory.make and so on) always throw the exception

**SECOND UPDATE**
Here is the full stack trace generated by the assert

```
ASSERTION_FAILED ([5.2]:AdvanceChunk():decodable-online-looped.cc:223) : 'current_log_post_.NumRows() == info_.frames_per_chunk / info_.opts.frame_subsampling_factor && current_log_post_.NumCols() == info_.output_dim'

[ Stack-Trace: ]

kaldi::MessageLogger::HandleMessage(kaldi::LogMessageEnvelope const&, char const*)
kaldi::MessageLogger::~MessageLogger()
kaldi::KaldiAssertFailure_(char const*, char const*, int, char const*)
kaldi::nnet3::DecodableNnetLoopedOnlineBase::AdvanceChunk()
kaldi::nnet3::DecodableNnetLoopedOnlineBase::EnsureFrameIsComputed(int)
kaldi::nnet3::DecodableAmNnetLoopedOnline::LogLikelihood(int, int)
kaldi::LatticeFasterOnlineDecoder::ProcessEmitting(kaldi::DecodableInterface*)
kaldi::LatticeFasterOnlineDecoder::AdvanceDecoding(kaldi::DecodableInterface*, int)
kaldi::SingleUtteranceNnet3Decoder::AdvanceDecoding()
```

Comment: `parameters snipped` is a bad idea. Overall, if you need an answer you need to provide more details.

Comment: Well I expected that the Kaldi Gst Element would negociate its caps as any other Gst plugin, that's the reason why I didn't provide the parameters. I just wanted to understand what it means. I don't have access to the parameters right now but I will provide it to you asap.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, I just added the parameters in the question

Comment: Ok, and what model is this? For newer models you need to add frame subsampling factor probably.

Comment: A brand new nnet3 model I got from a subcontractor but it's working without any frame subsampling using textual representation.

Comment: So, back in the troubles. In order to make our model work we need the subsampling factor but adding it to the preperties triggers the assert in Kaldi. After reading the code from the kadli gst server (https://github.com/alumae/kaldi-gstreamer-server ), we've seen that data is sent by the client as chunks of samplerate/4. Why this specific value ?

Comment: You need to provide more information about assert. Chunk size samplerate/4 is unrelated, it could be pretty arbitrary. Samplerate/4 is 1/4 of second, which is reasonable value for fast response.

Comment: I updated the main question to provide the whole stack trace. If I talked about the mysterious _samplerate/4_, it is only beacause that's the only difference I can see between the _kaldi-gstreamer-server_ and our code. Moreover, it seems to show that the gst plugin can't work in a simple chain when adding the subsampling factor parameter.

Comment: Changing _samplerate/4_ does not trigger the assert but has an impact on transcription quality.  I will go on searching what is done in the worker code of _kaldi-gstreamer-server_ to find what might be the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally got it working, even with *frame-subsampling-factor* parameter.

The problem resides in the order of the parameters.
*fst* and *model* parameters have to be the last ones.

Thus the following textual chain works :

```
gst-launch-1.0 pulsesrc device=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_05.0.analog-stereo ! queue ! \
           audioconvert ! \
           audioresample ! tee name=t ! queue ! \
       kaldinnet2onlinedecoder \
       use-threaded-decoder=0 \
       nnet-mode=3 \
       word-syms=/opt/models/fr/words.txt \
       mfcc-config=/opt/models/fr/mfcc_hires.conf \
       ivector-extraction-config=/opt/models/fr/ivector-extraction/ivector_extractor.conf \
       phone-syms=/opt/models/fr/phones.txt \
       frame-subsampling-factor=3 \
       max-active=7000 \
       beam=13.0 \
       lattice-beam=8.0 \
       acoustic-scale=1 \
       do-endpointing=1 \
       endpoint-silence-phones=1:2:3:4:5:16:17:18:19:20 \
       traceback-period-in-secs=0.25 \
       num-nbest=2 \
       chunk-length-in-secs=0.25 \
       fst=/opt/models/fr/HCLG.fst \
       model=/opt/models/fr/final.mdl \
       ! filesink async=0 location=/dev/stdout t. ! queue ! autoaudiosink async=0
```

I opened [an issue](https://github.com/alumae/gst-kaldi-nnet2-online/issues/62) on GitHub for this as for me, this can be really difficult to find and should at least be documented.